# How to Build Tree from String in JDT Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt

I get AST as string by jDT compiler as:

> MethodDeclaration ArrayType SimpleType SimpleName Object SimpleName
>   method SingleVariableDeclaration PrimitiveType int SimpleName x Block
>   VariableDeclarationStatement PrimitiveType int
>   VariableDeclarationFragment SimpleName y IfStatement NumberLiteral
>    ReturnStatement NumberLiteral  ReturnStatement
>   InfixExpression + SimpleName xNumberLiteral

for the method:

```
Object[] method(int x) {
     int y;
     if(1)
        return 1;
     else
        return x+3;
 }
```

How could I Convert the above AST String to tree which this help me to traverse on this tree by any method?

Here is my code:

```
    srcCode = "class t { Object[] method(int x) {int y;if(1)return 1;else return x+3;}}";
    ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS3);
    parser.setSource(srcCode.toCharArray());
    parser.setResolveBindings(true);
    parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
    final CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit) parser.createAST(null);

    cu.accept(new ASTVisitor() {
        @Override
        public boolean visit(MethodDeclaration node) {
            ast += node.getClass().getSimpleName() + " ";
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean visit(VariableDeclarationFragment node) {
            // System.out.println(node.getClass().getSimpleName());
            ast += node.getClass().getSimpleName() + " ";
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean visit(TypeDeclaration node) {
            // System.out.println(node.getClass().getSimpleName());
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean visit(SimpleName node) {
            // System.out.println("----> "+node.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + node);
            ;
            ast += node.getClass().getSimpleName() + " " + node ;

            List<ASTNode> children = getChildren(node);
            // System.out.println(node.getIdentifier());
            return false;
        }

        public boolean visit(ReturnStatement node) {
            // System.out.println(node.getClass().getSimpleName());
            ast += node.getClass().getSimpleName() + " ";
            System.out.println(node.getParent().getParent());

            ASTNode parentNode = node.getParent();

            // tree.addNode(node.getClass().getSimpleName(),);
            return true;
        }

        public boolean visit(SingleVariableDeclaration node) { //
            System.out.println(node.getClass().getSimpleName());
            ast += node.getClass().getSimpleName() + " ";
            return true;
        }
```

and so on for all subclasses

Comment: The `CompilationUnit` returned by `parser.createAST` is already the tree. See its methods such as `types()`. The `accept` method you are using just traverses through that tree.

Comment: **types()** return the List of source code (code above) not AST. can you help me to catch AST Tree?

Comment: What you have shown above are all parts of the AST. I believe the list returned by `types()` is a list of `AbstractTypeDeclaration` (usually `TypeDeclaration`) which again has methods to get the child tree nodes.

Comment: Yes, I have written this line **TypeDeclaration l = (TypeDeclaration)cu.types();**
but I get this error :
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.ASTNode$NodeList cannot be cast to org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom.TypeDeclaration

Comment: It is a List that is returned - you have to iterate through the list, there may be more than one type declared in compilation unit.

Comment: I know that it's a list and when I iterate over it, it return the code itself.
but when I add this line TypeDeclaration l = (TypeDeclaration)cu.types(); 
I got that error, I guess this error that not compatible types (ASTNode and TypeDeclaration)

Comment: It does not return the 'code itself', it returns a list of AbstractTypeDeclaration objects.

Comment: @AhmedRamadan, show us that you know how to iterate a list and then people can help you from there.

Comment: when I add this line **System.out.println(cu.types());** it display the following: <
[ class t {
  Object[] method(  int x){
    int y;
    if (1)     return 1;
 else     return x + 3;
  }
}
]
Can you help me?